# Postgres 12: why does stored procedure start slowing after running many times

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I am running a stored procedure repeatedly on Postgres 12, each time for a different date. Initially, the stored procedure takes between 3 and 10 seconds to run but after running it many times in a row, for about an hour, the stored procedure starts taking much longer (about 1 minute or longer).

Simple queries of the table used in the stored procedure also start taking much longer than usual to run. After running a VACCUUM ANALYSE on this table the queries speed up again.

I am wondering where the issue could be that causes the query to start running so slow.

I have run an Explain(Analyse, Buffer) on a simple query from part of the stored procedure and saved it in the following links, also happy to share an Explain(Analyse, Buffer) of the full stored procedure.

Explain(Analyse, Buffer) when the stored procedure is quick: https://explain.depesz.com/s/yrse

Explain(Analyse, Buffer) when the stored procedure is slow: https://explain.depesz.com/s/uQel

Code which produced the Explain(Analyse, Buffer)

```
SELECT period_id, classification_id,dtz,now() as create_dt,now() as update_dt,
                       false as latest_record,ratio_1
    FROM zpart.ratios_y2020 r
    where  classification_id is not null and universe_weight is not null
      and dtz='2020-03-28 00:00'::timestamptz
```

Below is the code of the stored procedure for a specific date.

```
create temp table t_rr as
with cte as (
    SELECT period_id, classification_id,dtz,now() as create_dt
             ,now() as update_dt,false as latest_record,ratio_1
    FROM zpart.ratios_y2020 r
    where  classification_id is not null and universe_weight is not null
      and dtz='2020-03-28 00:00'::timestamptz
)
SELECT period_id, classification_id,dtz,now() as create_dt,now() as update_dt,false as latest_record
     , percentile_cont(array(SELECT generate_series(0, 99) :: NUMERIC / 100)) WITHIN GROUP
                                 (ORDER BY ratio_1) AS lower_bounds_1
FROM cte r
GROUP BY period_id, classification_id, dtz
union all
SELECT period_id, 1 as classification_id,dtz,now(),now(),false
     ,percentile_cont(array(SELECT generate_series(0, 99) :: NUMERIC / 100)) WITHIN GROUP
                                 (ORDER BY ratio_1) AS lower_bounds_1
FROM cte r
GROUP BY period_id, dtz
union all
SELECT  period_id, 2 as classification_id,dtz,now(),now(),false
     ,percentile_cont(array(SELECT generate_series(0, 99) :: NUMERIC / 100)) WITHIN GROUP
                                (ORDER BY ratio_1) AS lower_bounds_1
FROM cte r
where  classification_id!=3
GROUP BY period_id, dtz;

insert into zpart.rank_ranges_y2020(period_id, classification_id, dtz, create_dt, update_dt,
latest_record, lower_bounds_1)
SELECT period_id, classification_id, dtz, create_dt, update_dt, latest_record,lower_bounds_1
FROM t_rr r
on conflict (dtz,period_id,classification_id) do update set update_dt=now(),
latest_record=EXCLUDED.latest_record,lower_bounds_1=EXCLUDED.lower_bounds_1;
truncate t_rr; drop table if exists t_rr;
```

**EDIT**
Problem was being caused by the ReadIOPs bursting above it's allocation which over time caused the database to slow down.

Comment: What is the definition of the index?

Comment: Please show the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for those queries, preferably after turning on `track_io_timing`

Comment: I've updated the links in the post to show output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`. The index on the table is defined as unique on (security_id, period_id, dtz). The table is also partitioned by period_id which is why you will see table names like ratiosy2020p9 in the explain analyse. There are 7 different period_ids (1, 9, 11, 12, 14, 15, 17).

Comment: Are you leaving transactions open?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a very good index for this query.  You need an index whose first column is `dtz`.  Your existing index is being read entirely in order to find the rows it needs, in other words it is not being used as a traditional index but rather just as a "skinny" table.

I don't know why the query goes from fast to slow. The difference is clearly in the IO timing, but it is not clear what is causing that.  It could just be that other activity in your system starts demanding its own IO, and the competition slows down the IO of the query you are looking at.  Or it could be that other activity is forcing the data you need out of the file-system cache.  But anyway, a better index should render that irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I changed the index on the table but it didn't make much difference. I contacted AWS and the problem was the Read IOPs was being throttled as it was going above the allocated IOPs of the database, eventually causing the queries to slow